# Java 'error: class expected' when usig array length method

Tags: java, class

I am doing an assignment for my Java class that requires me to write a program that displays the number of uppercase letters in a string. I am getting the error on my line 26 (for (int i = 0; i < ch[].length; i++){) any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Uppercase{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        char[] newWord;
        Scanner userWord = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a word");
        
        String word = userWord.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("There are " + newWord.numUppercase(word) + "uppercase letters");
    }
    
    public int numUppercase(String s){
        char[] ch = new char[s.length()];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
            ch[i] = s.charAt(i);
            
        int uppercase = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < ch[].length; i++){
            if(ch[i].valueOf() > 64 && ch[i].valueOf() < 91){
                uppercase++;
            }
        }
        return uppercase;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @azurefrog - That doesn't explain it.  In fact `ch[]` is parsed as an array *type*; i.e. an array of some (unresolvable) **type** `ch`.  And the only valid syntax for a `<type> . <something>` is `<type> . class`.  Hence the weird message about expecting `.class` !!

Answer (score 0):

Your bug-fixed class:

```
public class Uppercase{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner userWord = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a word");

    String word = userWord.nextLine();

    System.out.println("There are " + numUppercase(word) + "uppercase letters");
}

public static int numUppercase(String s){
    char[] ch = new char[s.length()];

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        ch[i] = s.charAt(i);

        int uppercase = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < ch.length; j++){
            if(ch[j] > 64 && ch[j] < 91){
                uppercase++;
            }
        }
        return uppercase;
    }
    return 0;
}}
```

Comment: you have fixed only a few typos and formatting in the original code snippet but not the **bug** of calculating all-uppercase letters.  This code returns 0 for `aBCDEFGH` and 1 for `ABCDEFGH`.  Do you think it is bug-free?

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the typo, the calculation of the uppercase letters is incorrect.

First, there's no need to create `ch` array, copy the characters from the input string, and then check the chars in `ch` array.

Second, an assumption that the uppercase letters reside in the range `[65, 90]` is applicable only to English letters.  There are several `Character::isUpperCase` methods to check if a [character](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase-char-) or a [Unicode codepoint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase-int-) is upper case.  `Character::isUpperCase(char c)` has been existing for a while since Java 1.0.

So, that being said, an example counting uppercase letters could be as follows:

```java
public static int numUpperCase(String s) {
    int num = 0;
    if (s != null) {
        for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) num++;
        }
    }
    return num;
}
```

A oneliner using Stream API:

```java
static int numUpperCase(String str) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(str)
           .map(s -> (int) s.chars().filter(Character::isUpperCase).count())
           .orElse(0); // if input string is null
}
```